# Can I disable SFINAE?

Tags: c++

Suppose I have this program

```
struct A
{
  template <typename T>
  static auto fun() -> typename T::type { }
};

struct C
{
    // doh! I forgot to add a typedef for type!
};

int main() {
    A::fun<C>();
    return 0;
}
```

[Live example](http://ideone.com/All9Jq)

I might need the `auto` specifier for any number of reasons, but the above program produces the following error:

> ```
> prog.cpp:13:12: error: no matching function for call to ‘A::fun()’
>   A::fun<C>();
> ```

While true, it's not particularly helpful. It's obvious in this example that I forgot to provide a `C::type`, but you can see that in larger programs this might become very confusing.

The *real* reason for the failure is buried a few lines deeper in the compiler error message:

> prog.cpp:7:15: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘struct C’

In an actual code base this message could be under hundreds or thousands (or hundreds *of* thousands) of lines of error messages (and above an equally large set of messages that might have arisen from another change). Considering that in a real scenario we might not even know what to look for, this could be very confusing.

An error telling me simply that the declaration of `A` failed because `C::type` was not declared would have been much more helpful.

There are of course plenty of situations where SFINAE is useful and necessary, so I don't want to somehow turn off this language feature altogether. But can I *disable* the SFINAE rules for this particular function?

In other words, can I add something to the function declaration to *force* the compiler to attempt to compile the function, and produce an error if substitution failure occurs?

Comment: Can you provide a more realistic example? The template type must be used in the function parameter list to be deduced. Which compiler are you using, and what error does it generate?

Comment: @MarkRansom see updated example. It's highly simplified but I think it illustrates the problem.

Comment: And then it tells you "prog.cpp:4:15: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘struct C’" when it explains why you have a substitution failure.

Comment: `error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘struct C’` isn't enough?

Comment: @remyabel not in large codebases, no.

Comment: @Arman If you add `decltype`, the error message becomes `error: ‘Type’ is not a member of ‘C’`. Not sure if that helps any.

Comment: Why, what part of that error message becomes unclear as the size of the codebase increases?

Comment: @Praetorian the error messages are perfectly clear and correct, it's just that the root cause is somewhere amidst a sea of other errors because SFINAE is quite happy to kick the can down the road until someone actually tries to call the missing function. I've updated the question to hopefully clarify this, maybe I wasn't clear on that initially.

Comment: I still think you're overstating the problem. Yes, sometimes stuff like this can spew pages of errors, but that's something you learn to filter through. What I do in these cases is start with the first and last errors, these are usually more informative than looking at the intermediate messages. Hopefully we'll have concepts in C++17 and stuff like this will be caught at the first level instead of deep down in the bowels of a template instantiation. And if you want to see an unhelpful error message, take a look at [this](http://rextester.com/YQKB46513).

Comment: @Praetorian fair enough, thought it was worth asking though :)

Comment: And yes, that's pretty bad!

Comment: SFINAE only applies to the direct context, so one level of indirection disables it: `typename Wrap<T>::type` where `template<class T>struct Wrap{typedef typename T::type type;};` should do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to disable SFINAE. C++ has no features to enable and disable at will. There is a way to make the SF part never happen, so that the E is triggered elsewhere.

```
struct A
{
  template <typename T>
  static auto fun() -> typename get_type<T>::type { 
    static_assert(has_type<T>::value, "Template parameter has no type member named 'type'");
  }
};
```

`get_type` (that never fails) and `has_type` (using SFINAE) are standard exercises described everywhere.

Comment: There's also a flag to reduce the amount of template recursion that is allowed. I think it's `-ftemplate-depth` or something.. Lots of SFINAE uses it.

Comment: @Brandon: Not portable. n.m.'s answer is.